# unable to get exact results for select query with join

Tags: mysql, select, join

this is my query

```
 select count(fp.kat),fs.cid,fcc.cid
 from tbl1 fs
left join tbl2 fp  on fs.cid=fp.cid
left join tbl3 fcc on fcc.cid=fp.kat
group by fcc.cid,fs.cid
```

which output

```
count(fp.kat)       cid         cid

 3                1          3


 2                2          3

1                 3           4

2                 4           4
```

but i want the ourput as

```
   count       cid
     2            3

     2             4
```

i dont know whats the issue please let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select count(*), x
from
(
    select count(fp.kat),fs.cid,fcc.cid as x
    from tbl1 fs
    left join tbl2 fp  on fs.cid=fp.cid
    left join tbl3 fcc on fcc.cid=fp.kat
    group by fcc.cid,fs.cid
) y
group by x
```